# Wrong Website Title shows up in Google SERP

Tags: seo, search-results, yoast

I have set the title of my website in yoast as shown below in the screenshot.
[image]
But on SERP, different title shows up as shown below in the screenshot.
[image]
How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

> Why the search result title might differ from the page's  tag
>
> If we’ve detected that a particular result has one of the above issues
>   with its title, we may try to generate an improved title from anchors,
>   on-page text, or other sources. However, sometimes even pages with
>   well-formulated, concise, descriptive titles will end up with
>   different titles in our search results to better indicate their
>   relevance to the query. There’s a simple reason for this: the title
>   tag as specified by a webmaster is limited to being static, fixed
>   regardless of the query.
>
> When we know the user’s query, we can often find alternative text from
>   a page that better explains why that result is relevant. Using this
>   alternative text as a title helps the user, and it also can help your
>   site. Users are scanning for their query terms or other signs of
>   relevance in the results, and a title that is tailored for the query
>   can increase the chances that they will click through.
>
> If you’re seeing your pages appear in the search results with modified
>   titles, check whether your titles have one of the problems described
>   above. If not, consider whether the alternate title is a better fit
>   for the query. If you still think the original title would be better,
>   let us know in our Webmaster Help Forum.

[Taken from this Google webmaster's post.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en)

One of Google's suggestion seems to be the case in your site:

> Brand your titles, but concisely. The title of your site’s home page
>   is a reasonable place to include some additional information about
>   your site—for instance, "ExampleSocialSite, a place for people to meet
>   and mingle." But displaying that text in the title of every single
>   page on your site hurts readability and will look particularly
>   repetitive if several pages from your site are returned for the same
>   query. In this case, consider including just your site name at the
>   beginning or end of each page title, separated from the rest of the
>   title with a delimiter such as a hyphen, colon, or pipe, like this:
>
> ExampleSocialSite: Sign up for a new account.

The problem with your `title` tags seems to be that your domain name "taskmasters" is at the end of a not-so-short title, so it gets truncated in the search engine results page and google does not like it. Consider making your title shorter or moving your site name to the front so that "Taskmasters" does appear in the result page.